# WPF Ctrl+C Hotkey Registration Overrides/Stops Typical Copy Functionality

Tags: wpf, copy, registerhotkey

I have tried looking into this for a while now and have not been able to come up with an answer that has worked.  I am trying to register my WPF C# application to listen for Ctrl+C from anywhere while the application is running.  The code below is part of my application and does trigger when the user presses Ctrl+C, however, the contents of the Clipboard are stale (the contents are from a previous copy before the application was running).  The AnimateWindow function is being called so I know my hotkey registration is working.

So, my issue is that it appears registering for the hotkey below is overriding the copy functionality. I would like to keep this functionality intact as it is part of how my application works.  I need to take what was copied and use that data for a database query and to fill a TextBox.

This is just a snippet of the entire project, please let me know if additional example code is needed to help answer.  Thank you!

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    // CTRL + C Hotkey
    private const int COPY_ID = 9001;
    private const uint MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002; // Modifier: Control
    private const uint VK_C = 0x43; // 'C' key
    /* Registering the hotkeys to be monitored */

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        _windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(_windowHandle);
        _source.AddHook(HwndHook);

        RegisterHotKey(_windowHandle, COPY_ID, MOD_CONTROL, VK_C); // 'C' key

    }

    /* The hook for pressing a hotkey */
    private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_HOTKEY:
                switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case COPY_ID:

                        AnimateWindow();

                        break;
                }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Your intension is to (secretly) capture Ctrl+C hotkey? Is it right strategy in the first place?

Comment: I wouldn't say secretly...  I am developing an application that needs to capture text that is copied from another application and automatically do a database search.  So, it needs to know when a copy to the system clipboard is performed even when it is not in focus/minimized and then act upon it.  The idea is that it's seamless to the end user and they don't need to copy and paste it into the application's search bar.  It will need the 'metadata' that comes with a copy so we can know, for instance, what URL the text was copied from.